# Using arrow keys to select child li element of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, keyboard-events

I'm trying to build a menu with submenus that is all navigatable by keyboard. Essentially I have an unordered list, and each list item has another unordered list underneath it. I can navigate through my top-level  list like this:

```
var li = $('li.tile');
var liSelected;
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 40) {
        if(liSelected) { // just a boolean variable at this point?
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if(next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.first().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.first().addClass('selected');
        }
    } else if(e.which === 38) {
        if(liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if(next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected'); // not properly selecting last() because of submenu items ? 
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        } 
    } /* begin experiment*/ else if (e.which === 13){
      $(".selected").click();
    } 
});
```

Then I've tried adding this, just before the 'else if' statement to switch to the down key (case 38) -

```
 if(liSelected && ($(".subTile").is(":visible"))){
        $(".selected:first-child").addClass("selectedSub");
      }
```

I can't figure out why it isn't working.

I have two CSS classes, one for each level of the menu. 'selected' for top level layers and 'selectedSub' for lower level layers, all they do is change the background color of the item so the user knows where they are.

My submenus are hidden in the beginning, they are opened/closed like this:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
var i;


for (i=0;i<acc.length;i++){
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var $subItem = $("ul, li", this);
    this.classList.contains("active") ? $subItem.show() : $subItem.hide() ;
  })
}
```

I'm pretty new to code and very lost currently. 
Here's my codepen if that's helpful: https://codepen.io/kbeats/pen/YJWzeP

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the DOM directly is not a recommended practice.

It might be hard for you let this go (we've all been there), but try to re-write your code the following way. I'll share a pseudo-ish code of how I would have done.

```
$('.select').removeClass('select')

arrayOfListElems = [
   '#li-elem1', 
   '#li-elem1-1', // sub-menu of li-elem1
   '#li-elem1-2', // sub-menu of li-elem1
   '#li-elem2', 
   '#li-elem3', 
]
currIndex = 0;
maxIndex = currIndex.length - 1;

if(key is pressed){
  if(key is down-button){
    currIndex--;
    // makes sure currIndex isn't below 0
    currIndex = currIndex < 0 ? 0 : currIndex; 
  } else if(key is up-button){
    currIndex++;
    // makes sure currIndex isn't below 0
    currIndex = currIndex > maxIndex 
      ? maxIndex 
      : currIndex; 
  }
  currElem = arrayOfListElems[currIndex];

  // do stuff with the element:
  $(currElem).addClass('select')
}
```

This way, you only have to somehow get `arrayOfListElems` correctly, whether manually hard coding it or somehow getting it dynamically, the code will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried to write it out, but it's only adding the 'selected' class to my first element in the '.tile' class (my class for the top-level menu items). This is how I wrote it:
var myList = $(".tile").toArray();

currIndex = 0;
maxIndex = currIndex.length -1;

$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which===40){
    currIndex--;
    currIndex = currIndex < 0 ? 0 : currIndex;
  } else if(e.which==38){
    currIndex++;
    currIndex = currIndex > maxIndex ? maxIndex : currIndex;
  }
})


currElem = myList[currIndex];

$(currElem).addClass('selected');